# Try catch in Java - what happens when an exception occurs?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a question regarding try/catch and exceptions in Java. I know this should be basic knowledge, but I think I miss a part of the understand of how this works. Given this code for example:

```
String res = "";

try {
    res = methodThatCanThrowException();
    res = res + ".txt";
} catch (Exception e) {
    res = "somethingwentwrong.txt";
}

return res;
```

Am I guaranteed that 'res' will never be set both in the try AND the catch block? If an exception is thrown inside the methodcall in the try block, the code control goes directly to the catch block, right? Is there any scenarios where 'res' will be given a value both in the try and the catch block?

Comment: Your code won't compile. You should `catch` something..

Comment: Yes. Maroun is right. If you caught the exception. then res will be set to the value used in the catch block for sure

Comment: Seems you need to read about [`Exceptions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `methodThatCanThrowException` throws an exception, `res` won't get assigned in the `try` block, so only the `catch` block would assign it (assuming you fix your catch block).

However, even if the exception was thrown after `res` is already assigned, the catch block would overwrite it with a new value, so it doesn't matter if it is assigned by both.

Comment: Even if the exception that is thrown in the methodcall 'swallows' the exception?

Comment: @user16655 What exception swallows what exception? If `methodThatCanThrowException` throws an exception and catches it internally, this means `methodThatCanThrowException` didn't throw an exception to its caller, and the try block would assign a value to `res`.

Comment: Ah, but then it will not come to the 'catch' block in the example above if methodThatCanThrowException() handles the exception internally? That makes me a bit wiser :)

Comment: @user16655 Yes, if the exception is handled internally, the catch block in your snippet won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer you can get is from the [JLS - 14.20.1. Execution of try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1):

> A `try` statement without a `finally` block is executed by first executing the `try` block. Then there is a choice:
>
> ...
>
> If the run-time type of `V` is assignment compatible with (§5.2) a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the `try` statement, then the first (leftmost) such `catch` clause is selected. The value `V` is assigned to the parameter of the selected `catch` clause, and the Block of that catch clause is executed...

I don't want to paste the whole section because it's big, I highly advise you to go through it to better understand the mechanism of *try-catch-finally*.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. If `methodThatCanThrowException` throws an execption it will jump to  `res = "somethingwentwrong.txt";`. There is never a scenario with both lines excecuted

Answer (score 0):

If no exception takes place within the `try` block, the `catch` block will never be executed.

If, on the other hand, an exception does take place, control flow moves from the `try` block to your `catch` block, and the `res` variable would be overwritten with whatever it is you have in the `catch` block.

In your case, `res` will be have either whatever `methodTatCanThrowException()` returns with `.txt` appended to it or `somethingwentwrong.txt`.

As a side note, you might also want to look into the `finally` block and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception occurs inside a try block, control goes directly to the catch block, so no other code will be executed inside the try block and the value of res will not change. **Also when a method throws an exception it does not return anything**. So in case of an exception, res will only be set once when it is initialised outside the try catch block, and then later when inside the catch block.

Never more than twice